# how to find sum of cells surrounding a user input cell in 2d array?

Tags: c++

this is what I have so far with the srand(0) omitted for ease of calculation the values are close except for the outer limits. the formatting for the output is all correct but the sum value for the surrounding cells is usually in the millions if the chosen cell is on column or row 9.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int matrix[9][9];
    int row_n, col_n, sum, surround_sum, i, j;
    cout << "\t    columns" << endl;
    cout << "       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << "row " << i + 1 << "  ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "what array cell would you like to see? (press enter after each entry)" << endl;
    cout << "row = ";
    cin >> row_n;
    cout << "column = ";
    cin >> col_n;

    cout << "the number " << matrix[row_n - 1][col_n - 1] << " is in cell " << row_n << "," << col_n << endl;

        for (int i=(row_n-2);i<(row_n+1);i++){

            for(int j=(col_n-2);j<(col_n+1);j++){
                if (i>9||i<0)
                    i=0;
                if (j>9||j<0)
                    j=0;
                sum+=matrix[i][j];
                surround_sum= sum-matrix[row_n-1][col_n-1]+2;
            }}
    cout << "the sum of the cells surrounding cell " << row_n << "," << col_n << " is " << surround_sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *with the srand(0) omitted for ease of calculation* I commend you for an excellent plan.

Comment: Valid indexes into `int matrix[9][9]` are 0 through 8. Your check of `if (i>9||i<0)` permits `i == 9`, in which case `matrix[i][j]` exhibits undefined behavior. Similarly for `j == 9`

Comment: The `if`s moved in the 00:47 edit change the indices used in the `for` loops. This usually ends badly. Be very careful that you don't accidentally re-visit previously visited coordinates.

Comment: You are fairly close to debugging this on your own. You already know a problematic case (e.g. row 9). Use a debugger -- or walk through the code by hand -- and look at what is going on. Which values are being added to your `surround_sum`?

Comment: I am supper new to c++ so I really dont know how to use it and its features that well the debugger function wouldn't help me here if someone could post a potential solution would be helpful.

Comment: @user12300491 So what would benefit you is learning [how to debug programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).